# OpenVZ MySQL InnoDB won't start

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, debian, openvz

I have a OpenVZ Server with 4GB RAM and have tried to install MySQL on several distros (Ubuntu 12.04 64Bit, Ubuntu 12.10 64Bit, Debian 7 64Bit) and I always get the same errors:

```
 130718  6:57:27 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130718  6:57:27 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130718  6:57:27 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130718  6:57:27 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
130718  6:57:27 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
130718  6:57:27  InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN. Will make 5 attempts before giving up.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 1 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 2 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 3 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 4 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 5 failed.
130718  6:57:29  InnoDB: Error: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN after 5 attempts.
InnoDB: You can disable Linux Native AIO by setting innodb_use_native_aio = 0 in my.cnf
130718  6:57:29 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot initialize AIO sub-system
130718  6:57:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
130718  6:57:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
130718  6:57:29 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
130718  6:57:29 [ERROR] Aborting
```

except on Ubuntu 12.04 64 Bit, but I would like to use a newer release.

I have tried setting  `innodb_use_native_aio = 0` in my.cnf, but this doesn't help. I would be very gratefull if someone could help me with this problem :)

Comment: Then it didn't take, Make sure the `innodb_use_native_aio = 0` is added 
to the `[mysqld]` section of your `/etc/my.cnf` file.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is OpenVZ® kernel, you might have hit some limit you didn't properly set up. Try:

```
cat /proc/user_beancounters
```

and check if some rows there has non-zero `failcnt`. Adjust appropriately to fix.

Another thing is simply `chroot` into the VE in question, for e. g.:

```
chroot /vz/root/1064 /bin/bash
```

and try starting `mysqld` there directly to see if it's OpenVZ® related. Let us know if you need further advising.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](http://forum.openvz.org/index.php?t=msg&goto=44068&) there are two solutions:

- add in my.cnf in mysqld section **innodb_use_native_aio=0**

or

- **echo 65536 > /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr**

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't help. I guess i will go back to Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: First of all,  this is default setting, there's no need to tweak it usually.

Answer (score -1):

Edit your `my.cnf`:

```
ignore_builtin_innodb
default_storage_engine=MyISAM
```

you could also just add in:

```
skip-innodb
```

I think more software is compatible with the older MyISAM.  It's what worked for me with a custom Debian 7 kernel running a basic configuration.  Be warned I have not tested this in a production environment!